# Twilio JAR file setup error

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I encountered a java security exception when I'm trying to compile with twilio jar.

Here is the error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.http.Consts"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

I suspect that there is one or more JAR files in my current setup have conflicted with twilio JAR.

Has anyone tried to call twilio API without using JAR file? By using restTemplate?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your project compile without the Twilio JAR?

Comment: Yes, it does. The only new JAR I added is Twilio.